# Find if a column value exists in multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 excel files - 'a1.xlsx','a2.xlsx','a3.xlsx','a4.xlsx'
The format of the files are same

for eg a1.xlsx looks like:

```
id    code    name
1      100    abc
2      200    zxc
...    ...    ...
```

i have to read this files in pandas dataframe and check whether the same value of `code` column exists in multiple excel files or not.

something like this.

if `code=100` exists in `'a1.xlsx','a3.xlsx'` , and `code=200` exists only in `'a1.xlsx'`

final dataframe should look like:

```
code    filename
100   a1.xlsx,a3.xlsx
200   a1.xlsx
...   ....
and so on
```

I have all the files in a directory and tried to iterate them through loop

```
import pandas as pd
import os
x = next(os.walk('path/to/files/'))[2]  #list all files in directory
os.chdir('path/to/files/')

for i in range (0,len(x)):
    df = pd.read_excel(x[i])
```

How to proceed? any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
import glob 

#get all filenames 
files = glob.glob('path/to/files/*.xlsx')
#list comprehension with assign new column for filenames
dfs = [pd.read_excel(fp).assign(filename=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in files]
#one big df from list of dfs
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
#join all same codes
df1 = df.groupby('code')['filename'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```